# recursive diff with per-file preprocessing

Tags: bash, diff

How do I get a combined effect of `diff -r left_dir right_dir` and `diff <(cat left_file | myfilter) <(cat right_file | myfilter)` without much scripting?

Answer (score 2):

If your file names are simple (no whitespace etc.), you can use

```
left_dir=...
right_dir=...
find $left_dir -type f | while read left ; do
    relpath=${left#$left_dir}
    diff <(myfilter $left) <(myfilter $right_dir$relpath)
done
```

If this is already "much scripting" and there are still problems (whitespace in file names, non-existing files on one side, etc.), you are probably out of luck.

Comment: Should be easy to work with whitespace if you quote the variables properly, and `find … -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' …`

Comment: @slhck: Sure. I just took that as "too much scripting" ;-)

Comment: this implements a single level of recursion. to get it right one would need to do `find left -type d`, `find right_dir -type d`, dump left and right difference and apply your code to intersection.

Comment: @bobah: What do you mean? If `$left_dir/path/deeper/than/one` exists, relpath will be `path/deeper/than/one` and the diff will compare the file with `$right_dir/path/deeper/than/one`.

Comment: @choroba: you are right, my comment was misleading. the above code won't report empty directories and files present in right but missing in left (though modification to make it working is rather simple)